# javax - getSession returning null

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Pretty simple question, `request.getSession(true)` returns null as if refusing to create a session. I've restarted my machine and added memory to both Tomcat and IntelliJ. Any thoughts or fixes? My coworkers are stumped as it works for them no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using getSession(), no arguments, it is in the 2.1 servlet spec

Please refer to 
https://community.oracle.com/message/2915765#2915765

for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this post
https://freddebostrom.wordpress.com/2008/03/13/tomcat-55-getsession-returns-null/

There is a mention about

Based on this post(http://www.mail-archive.com/jetspeed-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg15009.html)

modifying the server.xml configuration file in Tomcat by adding

emptySessionPath="true"

will solve the problem.